# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'columns' referenced before assignment

Tags: python

I am trying to split up some results files into columns, however I am getting the error:

> UnboundLocalError: local variable 'columns' referenced before assignment

I'm fairly new to Python, what can I try next?

This is my script:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#import cv2
from statsmodels.stats.proportion import proportion_confint


def readResults(resultsFile):
    
    data = []
    obsID = int(resultsFile.split('\\')[-1][:-4])
    
    with open(resultsFile, 'r') as r:
        for line in r:                  # Loop through each line
            if line[0] == '#':          # Skip any comment lines
                if line[1] == 'T':
                    line = line.rstrip().strip('#')
                    columns = line.split('\t')
                    columns.insert(2, 'frame')
                    columns.append('obsID')
                    
                continue
            
            line = line.rstrip().split('\t')
            line.append(obsID)
            data.append(line)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
    
    print(df.info)
    # Set variable data types
    df = df.astype({'frame':'int64',
                    'hit_flag':'int64',
                    'x':'int64','y':'int64',
                    'flip_flag':'int64',
                    'ImageFile':'str'
                    })
    
    return df
```

Answer (score 0):

Check the file contents.

Your error is saying that `line[1] =='T'` is never true when `line[0] == '#'`. Therefore `columns` is never defined.

If you truly wanted to skip comments, and only create dataframes for *uncommented* lines where the second character in that line is `T`, that would look like this

```
with open(resultsFile, 'r') as r:
    columns = None
    for line in r:                  # Loop through each line
        if line.startswith('#'):    # Skip any comment lines
            continue
        if line[1] == 'T':
            line = line.rstrip().strip('#')
            columns = line.split('\t')
            columns.insert(2, 'frame')
            columns.append('obsID')
                
            
        line = line.rstrip().split('\t')
        line.append(obsID)
        data.append(line)

if columns is not None:    
    df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=columns)
else:
    raise ValueError("No line has a second letter that equals 'T'")
```